# TypeError after upgrading to UI Bootstrap version 0.11.0

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

When I have upgraded to UI Bootstrap version `0.11.0` I am getting the following error with the UI Datepicker:

`TypeError: Unable to get property 'split' of undefined or null reference`
`at createParser (http://localhost:1234/js/lib/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js:751:19)`

The date in the data is in the following format `2014-06-27T00:00:00`:

```
 <div class="ticketStartDate" ng-click="openAddStartCal($event, ticket)" ng-hide="currentTicketUpdating == ticket.TicketId && currentParameterUpdating =='startCal' && startCalSaving == true">
                <input type="text" 
                       datepicker-popup="dd MMM"
                       ng-model="ticket.StartDate" 
                       ng-change="saveEditStartDate(ticket)"
                       is-open="startEditTicketOpened && currentTicketUpdating == ticket.TicketId"
                       datepicker-options="dateOptions" 
                       date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)"
                       ng-required="true" 
                       close-text="Close" />
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you encountered was solved [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/commit/42cc3f269bae020ba17b4dcceb4e5afaf671d49b)  .. You need to change [what](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/commit/42cc3f269bae020ba17b4dcceb4e5afaf671d49b) they have modified in your js file .. I even changed my minified `ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.min.js` (just for fun :) .. and production ) ..anyway you could find the lines easily with `ctrl+f` .. I hope that solves your problem .. as it solved mine